# and another Nginx redirect rewrite syntax q

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

To begin with, let me apologise for asking yet another question referring this topic.
I think I have read through all of them in the past few days, and still can not figure out a working solution for my needs.

Essentially I need nginx to redirect:

www.example.com/images/subfolders/*.jpeg to images.example.com/subfolders/*.jpeg

I currently have this setup:

```
location /images/ {
   rewrite         ^/(.*) http://images.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
 }
```

And it kinda works, it redirects to the images.examle.com/images/*.jpeg , but what I need is it to skip the images folder, it will be much cleaner.

As well as that, has anybody seen some site with all of those symbols (^ ~ = + *)in nginx.cnfg explained ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location /images {
  rewrite ^/images(.*)$ http://images.example.com$1 permanent;
}
```

The explanation of the "^ ~ = + *" symbols can be found in the documentation of the [location directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location).